# Powershell custom class creation question

Tags: powershell, exception, powershell-5.0, new-object

As I'm ramping up on PowerShell and exploring custom classes, I keep hitting this weird Exception that persists 'til I make any change.

```
> PS C:\Users\Purpl_000> C:\PS\Node\NodeTest.ps1 Cannot convert the
> "Node" value of type "Node" to type "Node". At
> C:\PS\Node\NodeTest.ps1:5 char:1
> + [Node]$node1 = New-Object Node -Property @{Next=$null; Value=3};
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [], ArgumentTransformationMetadataException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException   Exception setting "Next": "Cannot convert the "Node" value of type "Node" to type
> "Node"." At C:\PS\Node\NodeTest.ps1:9 char:1
> + $node2.Next = $node1;
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting   New-Object : The value supplied is not valid, or the property is read-only. Change the
> value, and then try again. At C:\PS\Node\NodeTest.ps1:13 char:16
> + [Node]$node3 = New-Object Node -Property @{Next=$node2; Value=9};
> +                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-Object], Exception
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetValueException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand  
> Cannot find an overload for "new" and the argument count: "2". At
> C:\PS\Node\NodeTest.ps1:22 char:1
> + [Node]$node4 = [Node]::new($node3, 12);
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

**Here's Node.ps1**

```
class Node
{
    [Node]$Next;
    [int]$Value;

    # .ctor
    Node([Node]$next, [int]$value)
    {
        $this.Next = $next;
        $this.Value = $value;
    }

    # default .ctor
    Node() {}


    static [int] Method1([Node]$n1)
    {
        return $n1.Value;
    }

    static [Node] Method2([Node]$n2)
    {
        $n2.Value = $n2.Value + 5;
        return $n2.Value;
    }
}
```

**Here's NodeTest.ps1**

```
. 'C:\PS\Node\Node.ps1';

[Node]$node1 = New-Object Node -Property @{Next=$null; Value=3};
[Node]$node2 = [Node]::new();
$node2.Next = $node1;
$node2.Value = 5;

[Node]$node3 = New-Object Node -Property @{Next=$node2; Value=9};

[Node]$node4 = [Node]::new($node3, 12);
```

I'm working in the PowerShell ISE. **Node.ps1** is saved and ran successfully. **NodeTest.ps1** is also saved but blows **sometimes** up **until** I do any seeming irrelevant change to the file, save, then **Run Script** again. At this point, it works fine again. Examples of changes that has resolved the issue: (1) Adding an extra line of blank space, (2) Removing an extra line of blank space, (3) Adding a comment, etc..

I understand

```
New-Object : The value supplied is not valid, or the property is read-only. Change the value, and then try again.
```

through my testing of what happens when you use the incorrect types but not quite sure why I'm intermittently seeing this. An easy example of intentionally repro'ing that error by passing an **int** where a **Node** is expected. :)

```
[Node]$node3 = New-Object Node -Property @{Next=5; Value=9};
```

The follow does confuse me. How can a **Node** not be a **Node** then magically a **Node** again after adding a blank line to **NodeTest.ps1**?

```
Exception setting "Next": "Cannot convert the "Node" value of type "Node" to type "Node"."
```

Any information, explanation, or education would be extremely appreciated!

Thanks all!
Michael

Comment: Are you running the debugger in a fresh console each time you try to test?  You cannot "unload" classes.  They require a new session each time.

Comment: That's interesting. Thanks for pointing that out! I'm just pressing the "Run Script" button in the ISE. I'm not reloading/refreshing/etc.

 I am still puzzled how adding or removing an extra blank line would fix the issue though.

Comment: Because you're changing the definition of the class so it's being reloaded (I think).  I haven't used the powershell class system very much since it's still very infantile in its implementation, but you can configure vscode to run the debugger in a temporary console

Comment: This puts some things into perspective wrt **Node** not being a **Node**. I suspect  that the **Node** in the **Node.ps1** file represents a different, same named **Node** class in the **NodeTest.ps1** file when that second script gets reran. What's puzzling is, how do they once again represent the same underlying **Node** class again?

Comment: This is why you don't try to debug classes without fresh sessions!

Comment: So for a fresh session, do I need to close and reopen the ISE? This would make testing incremental changes during my learning/ramping up process quite painful lol.

Eg., "What happens if I change this one character or statement in a minor way? How does PowerShell respond?"..... "This works in C#, let's see if it also works in PS!" .... etc..

Part of what helps my learning process is just tinkering around with the code/script after learning something new and seeing what happens.

Comment: You should modify your launch.json settings in vscode.  It will make testing this 1000 times easier

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue stems from having objects of type `[node]` in the current powershell session, then redefining the `[node]` type. It seems there are distinct definitions of `[node]` based on file content.

What may help make this a bit clearer is using `[node].guid` to see the distinct definitions of your class.

Here is a simple reproduction that demonstrates the issue:

classa1.ps1:

```
#class A def 1
class A {
    [A] $next
}
```

testclassa.ps1:

```
. ./classa1.ps1
$aobj1 = new-object A
Write-Host "Current A definition GUID: $([A].guid)"

" " | out-file  -Append ./classa1.ps1
. ./classa1.ps1
$aobj2 = new-object A
Write-Host "New A definition GUID: $([A].guid)"

# throws conversion exception because the type definition of 
# $aobj1.next now differs from the current [A] definition
$aobj1.next = $aobj2
```

```
Exception setting "next": "Cannot convert the "A" value of type "A" to type "A"."  
At /home/veefu/src/throwaway/testclassa.ps1:13 char:1
+ $aobj1.next = $aobj2
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting
```

It seems the type system treats the two versions of `[A]` as distinct types without conversion between them, despite the actual definition of `[A]` being identical.

If tinkering is your style of learning, familiarity with the `.gettype()` method and `| format-list *` expression will serve you well. These lend insight into the types and properties of objects PS creates for you. Opaque errors coming from code that should "just work" are often clarified by checking the type of the object being returned. I recall many times my scripts expect a single object and had some strange behavior or error, where `.gettype()` clarified that my script was actually being given a collection of objects.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the Guids seem to match. The error is only happening when using **New-Object** and not when using **[Node]::new($node2, 33)**

    `Inside Node.ps1!     Node Guid:  5ed04c38-857e-37b4-8615-6a200626bd78
    Inside NodeTest.ps1! Node Guid:1 5ed04c38-857e-37b4-8615-6a200626bd78
    Cannot convert the "Node" value of type "Node" to type "Node".
    At C:\PS\Node\NodeTest.ps1:6 char:1
    + [Node]$node1 = New-Object Node -Property @{Next=$null; Value=3};`